# Using PowerShell to replicate right clicking a folder and selecting properties

Tags: powershell, properties, directory, exe

I am trying to gather the Size/Size on disk and number of files/folders on a very large folder tree.

I have been using a script like the follow to gather some of this:

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\test" -recurse | Measure-Object -Sum Length | Select-Object `
  @{Name="Path"; Expression={$directory.FullName}},
  @{Name="Files"; Expression={$_.Count}},
  @{Name="Size"; Expression={$_.Sum}}

Path                                            Files                      Size
----                                            -----                      ----
C:\test                                         470                    11622961
```

But when I want to gather information on the number of folders and size on disk I'm having to run a separate script; which recuse through the folder tee again (Which takes a long time).

Is there an easy way of accessing the all this information the same way you can get it when you right click a folder and select properties shown below?

Are there any callable .exe files within system32 that can do this?

[image: Folder Properties]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have to accumulate your data in a custom object as you see each item:

```
$path = "C:\Users\aaron\Projects\Carbon"
$properties = New-Object PsObject -Property @{ 'Path' = $path; 'Files' = 0; 'Folders' = 0; 'Size' = 0 }
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse |
    ForEach-Object {
        if( $_.PsIsContainer )
        {
            $properties.Folders++
        }
        else
        {
            $properties.Size += $_.Length
            $properties.Files++
        }
    }
$properties
```

Comment: +1 Does the job well, do you know of anyway to get the 'size on Disk'?

Comment: @RichardOsborn That I don't know.  I see another Google search or StackOverflow question in your future... :-)

Answer (score 2):

According to [this answer](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/cd98b6ec-5a8c-4edb-80ed-045aed2739d4/help-querying-files-to-return-size-on-disk) in the Technet forums you can calculate the size on disk like this:

```
$afz = [MidpointRounding]::AwayFromZero
[math]::Round($_.Length / $clusterSize + 0.5, $afz) * $clusterSize
```

`$clusterSize` can be determined with the `fsutil` command (e.g. for drive `C:`):

```
PS C:\> fsutil fsinfo ntfsinfo C:\
NTFS Volume Serial Number :       0x648ac3ae16817308
Version :                         3.1
Number Sectors :                  0x00000000027ccfff
Total Clusters :                  0x00000000004f99ff
Free Clusters  :                  0x0000000000158776
Total Reserved :                  0x00000000000003e0
Bytes Per Sector  :               512
Bytes Per Physical Sector :       512
Bytes Per Cluster :               4096
Bytes Per FileRecord Segment    : 1024
Clusters Per FileRecord Segment : 0
...
```

Note that running `fsutil` requires admin privileges.

With that you can collect the information you're interested in like this:

```
$rootDir = "C:\test"

$afz = [MidpointRounding]::AwayFromZero
$clusterSize = fsutil fsinfo ntfsinfo (Get-Item $rootDir).PSDrive.Root `
  | Select-String 'Bytes Per Cluster' `
  | % { $_.ToString().Split(':')[1].Trim() }

$stat = Get-ChildItem $rootDir -Recurse -Force `
  | select Name, Length, @{n="PhysicalSize";e={
      [math]::Round($_.Length / $clusterSize + 0.5, $afz) * $clusterSize
    }}, @{n="Folder";e={[int]($_.PSIsContainer)}},
    @{n="File";e={[int](-not $_.PSIsContainer)}} `
  | Measure-Object -Sum Length, PhysicalSize, Folder, File

$folder = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
    "FullName"   = $rootDir;
    "Files"      = ($stat | ? { $_.Property -eq "File" }).Sum;
    "Folders"    = ($stat | ? { $_.Property -eq "Folder" }).Sum;
    "Size"       = ($stat | ? { $_.Property -eq "Length" }).Sum;
    "SizeOnDisk" = ($stat | ? { $_.Property -eq "PhysicalSize" }).Sum - $clusterSize;
  }
```

Comment: Works great apart from the 'Size On Disk' calculation doesn't give the correct value. As it's around +0.5% out from the when you manually look at the folder properties value.

Comment: It seems you have to subtract the cluster size from the result. Also you have to add `-Force` to `Get-ChildItem` to include hidden files.

Comment: Yeah that has improved the result making it within +0.03% of the manual lookup